# Add Item into a a tableView ?!

Tags: xcode

Hi I'm trying to create a dynamic tableView by the following method. But I'm getting an error during execution of the simulator. it works with a pre declared NSArray, but the following method doesn't work. Could you please help me on this topic ?

```
NSMutableArray *mesProduits;
mesProduits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellule];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellule];
    }
    for(int index = 0; index < [myObjectsFormulas count]; index = index+13)
    {
        monTest = [myObjectsFormulas objectAtIndex:monIndex];
        monIndex = monIndex+13;
        [mesProduits addObject:monTest];

    }
    NSString *celltext1 = [mesProduits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = celltext1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method then do like following:

```
// Declare mesProduits as a property 

- (void) viewDidLoad {  

    // Initialize and assigned values to monIndex and myObjectsFormulas 

    self.mesProduits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int index = 0; index < [myObjectsFormulas count]; index = index+13)
    {
        monTest = [myObjectsFormulas objectAtIndex:monIndex];
        monIndex = monIndex+13;
        [self.mesProduits addObject:monTest];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellule];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellule];
    }
    NSString *celltext1 = [self.mesProduits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = celltext1;
}
```